# Set Default Schema for Django in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x, schema

I am brand new to django, and I am working on setting up the basics of my first project and first app. I migrated my models to SQL Server, and all of the tables showed up under the schema dbo (default schema). I followed the direction of another SO question and set my default schema from within SQL Server to the schema of my choice. I deleted my migration history and migrated again from django. All the tables were created in the dbo schema again.

I see that I can set `db_table` in the Meta class of Models. However, I also am seeing on other questions that specifying a schema here doesn't always allow for migration changes, writes, etc.

Is it possible to set the schema for django to use?

**Edit:** I tried specifying a schema with this `db_table = 'myschema\".\"mytable'`. This resulted in django just creating the model as `dbo.myschema.mytable`.

I'm also seeing that `set_search_path` is an option for some databases, but it is not an option for SQL Server.

Comment: By what process are you migrating your tables? If the tables exist in the `dbo` schema, they'll remain on the `dbo` schema. The "default schema" only comes into play if you're creating a new table, and you don't specify a schema (which is bad practice).

Comment: i was creating new tables by migrating a model that i wrote. i guess that's the root of my question - how exactly do i specify a schema in django?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for MSSQL:

```
db_table = '[schemaname].[tablename]'
```